# Receiving 403 error when saving Joomla 3.4.8 article with php embedded

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-403

I've had this working in the past (earlier version of Joomla), but must have changed something and I can't get it work (even in a brand new site).  I'm using Joomla 3.4.8, the newest version of JCE, and DirectPhp.
I have Global Configuration > Text Filter Settings > Super Users set to No Filtering, and have adjusted JCE Administration > Editor Profiles > Default > Editor Parameters > Advanced > Allow PHP to yes.

Yet, when I save a any article with Php code I get a 403 error.  Without the php code it saves correctly.

Does anybody have any hints?

Comment: Thanks Mirko, I had no idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Many of our clients are facing the same problem. It turned out it is related to their host forcing browser caching on non-static content. Please follow the guide here ( http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-disable-browser-caching-in-joomla-backend ) and add the appropriate code to the .htaccess file to prevent browser caching. Please post back here if it fixes your problem or not.

Comment: Hi itoctopus,

Thanks for the link.  It didn't help.  I did try setting error reporting to maximum and it didn't alter the screen.  Here's the rest of the error text:

Error 403: Forbidden
You don't have permissions to access this page. This usually means one of the following:

this file and directory permissions make them unavailable from the Internet.
.htaccess contains instructions that prevent public access to this file or directory.
Please check file and directory permissions and .htaccess configuration if you are able to do this. Otherwise, request your webmaster to grant you access.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this that I worked out was to edit the php code in PHPmyAdmin directly.

It seems that mod_security on your apache server is causing the error to be forced when either your code is bad or is restricted. (this is not a bad thing as it stops hacking attempts on your site really.)

Going through phpMyAdmin requires a bit more skill but works all the same.

Anyway that is what I do now when I encounter this issue.  (the hard part is finding what is causing the error in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Probably mod_security is set to block PHP injection attacks, and it sees that as one. The way to tell is check the apache error log and the mod security audit log. Then, if you have access to the config files, you can configure an exception based around either that url or that variable to whitelist it from PHP injection checks.

WARNING: If you do that, be sure the code handling that form will be able to defend itself from injections, because you just stopped apache from defending it.

But the best solution for this is to write a plugin you can invoke from the content item, rather than inject all that code into your content. Makes it easier to maintain -- changes are localized instead of scattered across lots of database records. Change the plugin once and every page that needs it gets the change, instead of having to touch each and every item in the db to make that same change.

PS: There's a Joomla Stack Exchange. Check the list (top right, at time of writing).